# Executable file of Python script is not Working

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, can-bus

I have converted my python script(script.pyw) through auto-py-exe and my file is getting created as  successfully as script.exe. But when I am trying to run my Executable file it is showing error box which says "FAiled to Execute Script". But script is working fine in Terminal and IDE.

Here are the Libraries I am using in the script.

```
from PCANBasic import *        ## PCAN-Basic library import

 ## Imports for UI
  #from Tkinter import *          ## TK UI library
 #import Tix                     ## TK extensions library
 from tkinter import *
 from tkinter import tix
 from tkinter import messagebox
 from tkinter import font

 #import tkMessageBox            ## Simple-Messages library
 import traceback                ## Error-Tracing library

 import string                   ## String functions
 #import tkFont                  ## Font-Management library

 import time                     ## Time-related library
 import threading                ## Threading-based Timer library

 import platform                 ## Underlying platforms info library

 import time
```

Comment: is it working when u compiled it into console based exe?

Comment: This is solved now. I just need to move tix folder in current directory